# How to get a fileType from StorageReference in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I need to get the file type from StorageReference.ref, but when I try the getMetadata() method it runs to the following issue:

```
E/StorageException( 7358): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException( 7358): Object does not exist at location.
E/StorageException( 7358):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException( 7358): {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
E/StorageException( 7358): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
E/StorageException( 7358):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:455)
E/StorageException( 7358):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:435)
E/StorageException( 7358):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:426)
E/StorageException( 7358):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:280)
E/StorageException( 7358):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:294)
```

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage().ref().child(i);
storageReference.getMetadata().then((value) => print(value.toString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message "Object does not exist at location" is telling you that there is no object at the reference you created.  Check to make sure you're building the correct reference to the object that you want to get a download URL for.